# Showing an iff about finitely generated modules over PID's

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a PID and $M$ be a finitely generated torsion $R$ module. Show that $M$ is a cyclic $R$ module iff for any prime $p \in R$ either $pM = M$ or $M/pM$ is a cyclic R module.

Thoughts so far: I know I can apply the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over PID's to get an idea of the structure of $M$. I'm a little unsure of how you know when the product of torsion factors is cyclic. Any hints would be appreciated to get going with this problem.

Comment: Have you seen Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Image of cyclic module is cyclic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the structure theorem. We have $$M=\oplus_{i=1}^n R/(a_i)$$ where $a_i|a_{i+1}$ are the unique invariant factors of $M$ and where $(a_n)$ is the annihilator of $M$ in $R$. Clearly the only case where $M$ is cyclic is when there is only one invariant factor ($n=1$), because of the unicity of those factors. Then you get $pM=M$ or $M/pM$ cyclic depending if $p$ divides $a_1$ or not. Reciprocally, it is clear that if $M$ is not cyclic you can choose $p$ a common prime divisor of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$ and you get $M/pM$ contains $R/p\oplus R/p$ in its decomposition in invariant factor which is not cylic, right ? (the last invariant factor of $pM$ is $a_n/p$ so $M\neq pM$)

Considering your "counter-example", with $M=\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ you get $pM=0$ and $M/pM=M$ which is not cyclic.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will take a look as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @m.deslauriers thank you and take your time !